# Convert and compress multiple tif (image) files into one PDF with OCR

Tags: pdf, images, compression, ocr, tiff

I have found one old project that does exactly what I want! But it's broken somehow. Some crucial parts seems to be missing. It's a nightmare to configure. You can look at it here:

http://bookscanner.pbworks.com/w/page/40965440/FrontPage

I have decided to let that project be, I have tried on several different occasions to try to get it to work, without succeeding. The instructions are also unclear. Does anyone have another suggestion to some tool that can do what I want, as described in the title? Scantailor works perfectly. I'm missing the OCR and converting the TIF's into an actual PDF.

Comment: I confused about what you are trying to do.  Are you trying to: 
1.) scan in a book(s)/build a book scanner?  
2.) are you simply trying to convert multiple tifs to PDFs?
3.) would like the tif's run through OCR, so you have editable text?  Adobe Reader has built in OCR.  Could you give us the background of what your current situation, what you are trying to achieve, along with what you have already tried?

Comment: Also, what operating systems are you using?